# Append each chunk of strings to different url addresses

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, splice

Please take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UKq7E/13/)

I've broken an array into three small arrays using `splice`. Can anyone please show me how to append each of them to the url in the data source attributes in the example? I want the output to be like this:

```
<div class="site" data-source="http://url.com/?query=A|B"></div>
<div class="site" data-source="http://url.com/?query=C|D"></div>
<div class="site" data-source="http://url.com/?query=E|F"></div>
```

Example's HTML:

```
<div data-term="A" class="selector"></div>
<div data-term="B" class="selector"></div>
<div data-term="C" class="selector"></div>
<div data-term="D" class="selector"></div>
<div data-term="E" class="selector"></div>
<div data-term="F" class="selector"></div>

<div class="site" data-source="http://url.com/?query="></div>
<div class="site" data-source="http://url.com/?query="></div>
<div class="site" data-source="http://url.com/?query="></div>
```

jQuery:

```
    var terms = $('.selector').map( function() {
    return $( this ).data('term');
}),chunks;

while (terms.length > 0) {
    chunks = terms.splice(0,2);
    var see = chunks.join('|');
    console.log(see);   
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `attr()` :

```
/*get terms per OP code */

$('.site').attr('data-source',function(i, prev){
   return prev+terms.splice(0,2).join('|');       
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d6jbR/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$(selector).attr` functionality to retrieve and/or modify HTML attributes

Something like this should work:

```
$('.site').attr('data-source', $('.site').attr('data-source') + see);
```

If you give each of your elements an ID, you could select using that.

Comment: this will end up setting all the same, need to index them somehow

Comment: You are correct, but I did say `something like this`. God forbid someone might have to slightly adapt an answer that's being given to them in order for it to work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine:

```
var terms = $('.selector').map( function() {
    return $( this ).data('term');
}),chunks;

var counter = 0;
while (terms.length > 0) {
    chunks = terms.splice(0,2);
    var see = chunks.join('|');

    var siteDiv = $('.site:eq(' + counter + ')');
    var dataSourceText = siteDiv.attr('data-source');
    siteDiv.attr('data-source', dataSourceText + see);
    counter++;

    console.log('Old: ' + dataSourceText);
    console.log('New: ' + siteDiv.attr('data-source'));   
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w4rwH/

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
var index = 0;
while (terms.length > 0) {
    chunks = terms.splice(0,2);
    var see = chunks.join('|');
    $('.site').eq(index).attr('data-source',function(i,v){
       return v + see; 
    });
    index++;
    }
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/e9FTY/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 var terms = $('.selector').map( function() {
      return $( this ).data('term');
      }),chunks;

 var i = 0;

 while (terms.length > 0) {    
 chunks = terms.splice(0,2);
 var see = chunks.join('|');
 console.log(see);  
 var el = $($('.site')[i]);

 //changes attribute
 el.attr('data-source', el.data().source + see);

 //dont touch html attribute just changing data() value 
 el.data().source = el.data().source + see;
 i++;
}
```

and here is updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/baximilian/UKq7E/14/)